# Mixed content for audio file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, html5-audio

I have an mp3 file that I play using the audio source html tag like the following:

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

The problem is that the site is under https but the actual mp3 files are not (and for now they cannot be put under https). Because of that I get the following error:

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://parentpage.com' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure element http://horse.mp3

How can I make sure that I can play those mp3 files without them being under https?

Comment: You can load insecure content on your own browser by tweaking the security settings of your browser, but you can't do that for your users.

Comment: I don't think there's any way you can load insecure content without any modern browser complaining about it

Comment: How about if I open the file in a new window?

Comment: A new window might work, you've to test it. Also, you could try to load the mp3 via a proxy server ..?